# Search for Literal String

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, literals

I'm trying to find certain characters in a string and I receive the error "Unterminated string literal".

I'm searching for "\".  Is there a way to find this character (or other literal strings) without an error?

thanks,

Here is the simple function:

```
function test() {
  var a = "AGA_NAA1\MTH1.33";
  var rep = a.replace("\","-");
  Browser.msgBox(rep);
}
```

ERROR: Unterminated string literal.

Comment: Specify a language and show us what you have so far

Comment: Sorry, I'm working in Google Script and added the code to my question.

Comment: Try and use a double \, you are probably escaping the `"`, which does not end the string literal where you expect

Comment: Hans Kesting - Is this what you mean?  var rep = a.replace("\\","-");  That did not work.  It did not error, but it removed the "\" from my string.  At w3schools.com I'm able to get this literal to work with the following: var res = str.replace(/\\/g, "-");  But it does not work with Google Script

Answer (score 0):

I realize you are sharing a simplified example. However, this is happening because on variable a you also need double backslash because backslash is a special "escape" character:

```
function test() {
  var a = "AGA_NAA1\\MTH1.33";
  var rep = a.replace("\\","-");
  Browser.msgBox(rep);
}
```

Comment: JOE MILLER: I understand backslash is an escape character, but I don't know how to use it in a REPLACE or to find it in a string. Can you give an example?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you know that backslash is an escape character, then you also know that to write a backslash you need two backslashes together, while your question only has one (maybe Stackoverflow removed them from your post?) which is why I got the same error you did when I imported it to the script editor. The code I show here works on GAS, I tested it. Do you want me to show you how to do the same thing with replacing content from a cell? Like, "getCell(x,y).getValue().replace(...)"? Or are you trying to find the index/location of a backslash?

Comment: JOE MILLER - My apologies.  When I viewed your response on my iPad, it wasn't giving me your example.  I see it now on my desktop and